# w3c validation error on document type html 5

Tags: html, w3c

I am using html 5 for web page. When i validate my webpage in http://validator.w3.org/check it showed me the following error.

```
Line 1, Column 10: delimiter ">" invalid: only name, "#IMPLIED" and parameter separators are allowed

<!DOCTYPE>
```

If i change this it showed me lot of errors. How can i rectify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `<!doctype html>`

Read here on how you can validate HTML5 page on W3C Validator - http://www.werockyourweb.com/html5-validator